# Optimize Collatz Sequence

Tags: java, optimization

I have been working my way up in project-euler.net

I recently solved Problem 14- Please see [here](http://projecteuler.net/problem=14) for full description

Here is the code

```
public static void findHighestCollatzNumber()
{
    long greatestNumberOfTerms=0;
    long highestTermNumber=0;
    for(int i=1;i<=ONE_MILLION;i++)
    {
        long noOfTerms=getNumberOfCollatzTerms(i);
        if(noOfTerms>greatestNumberOfTerms)
        {
            greatestNumberOfTerms=noOfTerms;
            highestTermNumber=i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("highest number of term "+greatestNumberOfTerms + " for "+highestTermNumber);
}

public static long getNumberOfCollatzTerms(long n)
{
    long numberOfTerms=1;
    long i=n;
    do
    {
        i=calculateCollatz(i);
        if(i>0)
        {
            numberOfTerms++;
        }   
    }
    while(i!=1 && i>0);
    return numberOfTerms;
}


public static long calculateCollatz(long n)
{
    long collatz=0;
    if(n%2==0)
    {
        collatz=n>>1;
    }
    else
    {
        collatz=(n<<1)+1+n;
    }
    return collatz;
}
```

It gives the correct output, but it takes lot of time for computation

I have also tried to use bitwise operation for faster output, but still it takes time, how can I reduce it?

I already looked into other solutions but found most of them for ghc or C++ or Python.

Comment: Store previously calculated results in a data structure rather than recalculating them every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use a [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) to avoid recalculating the same numbers multiple times. Checking if the HashMap already contains the number is a quick process and can save you many steps.

For Example:
If you get to the number 200,000 for a second time, you already know how many more steps in the Collatz sequence.

Comment: but wouldnt that be for that specific number for eg 200,000 and not the other number

Comment: nub1-O-8: yes but you already know how many steps it took you to get to that number. At which point its just a matter of addition.